# GulpJS can no longer finds task in list properly (Gulp 4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, system

My gulp file pretty much looks like this (simplified)

```
function copyAssets () {
  return src(paths.assets, { base: './' })
    .pipe(cache('asset-files'))
    .pipe(dest(paths.build))
}

// Some more task functions

const build = parallel(copyAssets, brewCoffee, buildTypescript)

module.exports = { build, watch: series(build, watchFiles) }
```

But now when I list it it looks like:

```
[15:29:30] Tasks for .....
[15:29:30] ├─┬ <parallel>
[15:29:30] │ └─┬ <parallel>
[15:29:30] │   ├── copyAssets
[15:29:30] │   ├── brewCoffee
[15:29:30] │   └── buildTypescript
[15:29:30] └─┬ <series>
[15:29:30]   └─┬ <series>
[15:29:30]     ├─┬ <parallel>
[15:29:30]     │ ├── copyAssets
[15:29:30]     │ ├── brewCoffee
[15:29:30]     │ └── buildTypescript
[15:29:30]     └── watchFiles
```

And running things like `gulp build` will say that the task does not exist.

If I wrap the series / paralel function in an anonymised function I do see it appear in the list (like so)

```
const build = () => parallel(copyAssets, brewCoffee, buildTypescript)
module.exports = { build, watch: () => series(build, watchFiles) }
```

But then when running `gulp build` I'm getting

```
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

as an error.

I know at some point this did work (a number of months ago). But now for some reason it doesn't anymore. If I run `gulp --version` the output is:

```
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.0
```

edit: Hmmm. This seems to work

```
module.exports = { build: () => build(), watch: () => series(build, watchFiles)() }
```

But I doubt that's how I should actually do this stuff....

edit2: No, still broken, it runs now, and waits until completion. And then says the same error as before: `The following tasks did not complete: build`

Comment: What are the return values of `brewCoffee`, `buildTypescript`, and `watchFiles`?

Comment: Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

When I have used parallel (very briefly) in the past I had to reference it from gulp.

E.g. Change:

```
const build = () => parallel(copyAssets, brewCoffee, buildTypescript);
```

to:

```
const build = () => gulp.parallel(copyAssets, brewCoffee, buildTypescript);
```

The same with series here:

```
module.exports = { build, watch: gulp.series(build, watchFiles) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var srcPaths = {
    app: [
        'wwwroot/app/**/*.ts'
    ],
    js: [
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js',
        'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
    ],
}

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch([srcPaths.app, srcPaths.js], gulp.series('js'));
});
```

It will work fine. Enjoy!

Comment: That is the 'old' v3 syntax as far as I know. Which does work, but for clarification was not what I'm looking for, but thanks.